# Setting up allegro

Tags: dev-c++, allegro

Can anyone tell me how to set up allegro for devc++?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a detailed guide: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Dev-C%2B%2B

It applies to Allegro 5.0.* as well.